# back button issue in working with fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I am working on android app and use fragment for displaying user interface.
I am different fragment,i have two problem in app-
1. I am facing problem when user navigate from one fragment to another then multiple instance of same fragment is added in backstack.
Suppose user move from fragment1 to fragment2 then fragment3 and again move to fragment2 and thenpress back button then from backstack fragment3 is load and then fragment2 and then fragment1.so i just want to add a fragment one only in backstack.

I am creating only one instance of a fragment bu using my custom method for each fragment like-

```
public static Fragment getInstance(FragmentManager f){
    if(mFragment==null){
        mFragment = new HomeFragment();
    }
    fm = f;
    return mFragment;
}
```

so each time when a fragment is  replaced with a previous instance of same fragment.

2 after navigate to different screens when user presses virtual android mobile home button and app goes to sleep and after few hours if user again opens app then app force close.

Thanks in advance